# Olá, estou tendo problemas para rodar uma api criada com node. O servidor sobe sem problemas porém no navegador fica somente carregando. Código abaixo

Tags: node.js, api, express.js, firebird, firewall

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import { dbOptions } from "./config/database.js"
import firebird from 'node-firebird'

const app = express();


app.use(express.json);


app.use(cors());


app.get("/placas", function(req, res){

    firebird.attach(dbOptions, function(err, db) {

        if (err){
            return res.status(500).json(err);
        }

        db.query('SELECT * FROM TAB_VEICULO', function(err, result) {

            db.detach();
            
            if (err){
                return res.status(500).json(err);
            }else{
                return res.status(200).json(result);
            }

        });
    
    });    

});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("servidor no ar");
});
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Tenta imprimir os resultados que tão vindo em 'result'.
Pode ser que o erro esteja no trecho:

```
app.use(express.json);
```

Na verdade deveria ser - com o parênteses depois do .json, já que você tá chamando um método:

```
app.use(express.json());
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: É verdade, não me atentei a esse errinho, resolveu, muito obrigado!!

Comment: Se resolveu, fecha a pergunta!